# What's this curly brace comma syntax in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

What is this weird syntax you can use the the watch window (or even to set breakpoints) and where can I find it documented:

```
{,,test2.exe}<variable name>
```

[image]

When starting the program, the first will translate to my entry point and will break on execution start.

Intuitively I can see what this means, but where is it documented and what are the leading commas for (what stuff can you put in there)?

Why does using the syntax in the watch window help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the VS2015 [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2t7ahxk(v=vs.140)) states, that is called a Context Operator, valid only for C++ native applications.

You could put *function* and *source file* before the first and the second comma.

For VS2010 and previous versions the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wztycb7f(v=vs.100)) is slightly different and more verbose.